# Problems doing ajax-requests with a Phonegap application

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, rss, cordova

I'm trying to create a simple RSS reader with Phonegap and jQuery.
I am following this tutorial: http://visualrinse.com/2008/09/24/how-to-build-a-simple-rss-reader-with-jquery/.

**I've managed to get this working just fine when I try out the code in my browser.** The php-file fetches the feed and outputs it just like I expect it to. **But when I run the same file from within my compiled Phonegap application the ajax-request just returns the contents of the php-file** (the php-code, not the executed result).

I've spent hours Googling this and tried numerous tutorials and tweaks. I found no solutions in the offical Phonegap forums either. What am I doing wrong? The problem seems to be PHP not responding to the request. I've tried to move the php-file to a different domain but the result is the same, it works in my browser but not in the compiled app.

Here's the jQuery code that initiates the ajax-code:

```
function get_rss_feed() {
    //clear the content in the div for the next feed.
    $("#feed_content").empty().html('<img class="loader" src="js/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt=""/>');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://192.168.1.7/rssApp/www/rss-proxy.php?url=http://www.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/GlobalHome.xml',
        success: function parseRSS(d) {

        //find each 'item' in the file and parse it
        $(d).find('item').each(function() {

            //name the current found item this for this particular loop run
            var $item = $(this);
            // grab the post title
            var title = $item.find('title').text();
            // grab the post's URL
            var link = $item.find('link').text();
            // next, the description
            var description = $item.find('description').text();
            //don't forget the pubdate
            var pubDate = $item.find('pubDate').text();

            // now create a var 'html' to store the markup we're using to output the feed to the browser window
            var html = "<div class=\"entry\"><h2 class=\"postTitle\">" + title + "<\/h2>";
            html += "<em class=\"date\">" + pubDate + "</em>";
            html += "<p class=\"description\">" + description + "</p>";
            html += "<a href=\"" + link + "\" target=\"_blank\">Read More >><\/a><\/div>";

            //put that feed content on the screen!
            $('#feed_content').append($(html));
        });
        $('#feed_content img.loader').fadeOut();
    }

    });

};
```

Here's the **rss-proxy.php** that loads the XML from the url and outputs it:

```
<?php
    // PHP Proxy
    // Loads a XML from any location. Used with Flash/Flex apps to bypass security restrictions
    // Author: Paulo Fierro
    // January 29, 2006
    // usage: proxy.php?url=http://mysite.com/myxml.xml

    $session = curl_init($_GET['url']);                    // Open the Curl session
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);          // Don't return HTTP headers
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   // Do return the contents of the call
    $xml = curl_exec($session);                            // Make the call
    header("Content-Type: text/xml");                  // Set the content type appropriately
    echo $xml;        // Spit out the xml
    curl_close($session); // And close the session
?>
```

Comment: I'd advise removing that ip address from the code.

Comment: What happens when you open the `.php` file from the browser on the simulator or device? Does the PHP get executed?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I've tried to access the `.php` file from the browser in the simulator and it works. But it only works if I change the URL to be relative, not absolute: `url: 'rss-proxy.php?url=http://www.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/GlobalHome.xml'`. If I now use the mobile Safari browser to visit the index.html file in my www-folder of my Phonegap application which I am hosting on my local MAMP-server in my `htdocs` directory it works! But not from the compiled Phonegap app. And of course, the `.php` file is located in the www-folder along with the other script files.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**I've finally managed to solve this!**
It turns out that you need to whitelist the server you wish to request from your PhoneGap application in Xcode if you want to do requests to a certain domain (be it your localhost or whatever).
The reason that I didn't found this out earlier was that I didn't check for errors in the ajax response. Once I did that I got the http status code `401` (Unauthorized) and error message "`Whitelist rejected`".

To fix this I opened the file `PhoneGap.plist` in my project and under the key `ExternalHosts` i added a new item with the value: `*.localhost`. 
I also changed the ajax url to:

`url: 'http://localhost/rssApp/www/rss-proxy.php?url=http://www.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/GlobalHome.xml'`

**I compiled and run the application on the iOS Simulator and my localhost server responded with a perfectly successful ajax response!**

For every external host that you wish your application to connect to you must add it to the list of `ExternalHosts`. For example if you wish to access an API on http://google.com/maps/api.php you must add `*.google.com` to your list.

Kind of annoying when you try to figure out why the server isn't responding, but I guess it's good for security reasons. Hope this helps someone else out there who's struggling with simple ajax requests from their PhoneGap application!

Comment: Please accept your answer rather than writing "solved" in the question; if you have to wait a certain amount of time before you can do that, then wait that certain amount of time: there's a reason the system makes you.

Comment: Also, I might add, if you don't want to bother about any restrictions at all concerning `ExternalHosts` in your PhoneGap app, just add `*.*` and you will be allowed to send requests and receive responses to and from any server.

Comment: Sorry Tomalak, this is the first time I'm posting a question here. I'm not yet accustomed to the rules and customary practises. I've just seen that others have the "SOLVED:" prefix in their question.

Comment: Please point them out so that I may edit that out accordingly! In the meantime, our FAQ is a good read.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running your server locally (based on the 192.168.x.x IP address) which means that only devices connnected to your network can access it. You could connect the phone to the same wifi network as your computer as a temporary fix. But you're going to need to host this on a real server for it to be accessible over the internet.

You could also forward port 80 on your router to this IP address and then use your actual IP address (see whatsmyip.org) in your request url. But that's not a really stable solution.

Comment: Thanks Jason for your reply!
However, I've tried by uploading the php script to another external LAMP server hosted by a web-hotel and changed the url in my ajax-request, but this won't work either. In my browser such solution still works though.

The solution that I keep finding when I Google this is that it shouldn't be any harder than just typing any URL to any server side script and it should work:

Comment: For example: `ajax.open("GET","http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=bacon",true);`
But I cannot get this to work. 

By the way, I'm using the iOS simulator, not running the app on a physical phone. This should not be an issue however, I can access all the servers from the mobile Safari browser in the simulator.

Comment: The ajax bacon example from http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/42450600/PhoneGap%20Ajax%20Sample works fine on my Android devices

Comment: It sounds like your phonegap configuration is messed up. Did you follow all the steps for making a phonegap app listed here http://phonegap.com/start#ios-x4?